# How to not display the password match message on page load?

Tags: users, 8

In Drupal 8, by default, the `Passwords match:` message is visible on page load, then hidden after entering a first password and finally visible after entering the password again.

[image]

I would like to override this so that `style="display:none;"` or a specific class will be added to the "Passwords match:" div if no value has been entered in the "Confirm password" field.

Of course, it would be great if the "style="visibility:hidden"" and "style="visibility:visible;" could be removed as well.

How can I achieve this?